# remove current index from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the object that matches my if statement

my array:

```
[
   TextRow {
     id: 4,
     user_gender: 'Male',
     user_tags: '[]',
     user_birth: 26,
     user_lat: '34.03569255690516',
     user_lng: '-6.828115666526287',
     user_current_occupancy: 'None',
     user_biography: null,
     set_from_map: 1,
     info_verified: 0
   },
   TextRow {
     id: 5,
     user_gender: 'Male',
     user_relationship: 'Single',
     user_tags: '[]',
     user_birth: 19,
     user_lat: '32.8811',
     user_lng: '-6.9063',
     user_current_occupancy: 'None',
     user_biography: null,
     set_from_map: 1,
     info_verified: 0
   }
 ]
```

Here is a code snippet:
in distance function, I'm calculating the destination between the user and other users that I'm having them in the data array

```
data.map((value, i) => {

      const destination = parseFloat(
        distance(lat, long, value.user_lat, value.user_lng).toFixed(2)
      );
      // age_range is an array that have the range of age for example[16,26]
      if (
        destination > location_range ||
        value.user_birth < age_range[0] ||
        value.user_birth > age_range[1]
      ) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        i = i - 1;
      } else value.destination = destination;
    });
```

it didn't work for what I want, thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const data = newData.filter(el => {
const destination = parseFloat(
distance(lat, long, el.user_lat, el.user_lng).toFixed(2)
);
console.log(
destination > location_range ||
el.user_birth < age_range[0] ||
el.user_birth > age_range[1]
);
return !(
destination > location_range ||
el.user_birth < age_range[0] ||
el.user_birth > age_range[1]
);
});
data.forEach(el => {
const destination = parseFloat(
distance(lat, long, el.user_lat, el.user_lng).toFixed(2)
);
el.destination = destination;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.filter` instead of `data.map`

check this for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: is it possible to calculate the destination inside the filter function?

Comment: Yes, You edit the current item by reference, So the `destination` will be added to the original object